# There is a flicker when using <IonRouterOutlet> when navigating between pages in Ionic Capacitor with react app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

When adding pages via the  component there is a flicker and a flash of colour in the header bar. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Ionic Router trying to animate the page transition. This is solved by turning off the animation using:

```
<IonRouterOutlet animated={false}>
```